# student Gradejump in a historical data with the specific date they had gradejump

Tags: sql

I have a historical table holding daily student record. I want to get which date they had change of grade i.e from grade 3a to 3b as jump1 and from 3b to 5 jump2 with the relevant date. below is the script- problem with my script  I dont want all the rows that there is no jump.
""

```
WITH Grade1 AS(
SELECT DISTINCT  Employee as StudentID,BAND as Grade ,CensusDate AS GradeDate
FROM Gradehistory WHERE Band IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY  Employee,BAND ,CensusDate
),
Grade2 AS(
SELECT DISTINCT   Employee as StudentID,BAND as Grade ,CensusDate AS GradeDate
FROM Gradehistory WHERE Band IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY Employee, band , CensusDate
)
SELECT distinct A.StudentID,A.Grade as lowGrade ,B.Grade as Jumpgrade, B.GradeDate as JumpGradeDate
FROM Grade1 A INNER JOIN Grade2 B ON A.StudentID=B.StudentID
WHERE A.Grade < B.Grade 
GROUP BY A.StudentID, A.Grade, B.Grade, B.GradeDate
ORDER BY A.StudentID, a.Grade, JumpGradeDate ASC 

StudentID   lowGrade    Jumpgrade   JumpGradeDate
Ali 3   4   01/01/2017
Ali 3   4   01/06/2017
Sam 5   6   01/01/2017
Sam 5   6   01/03/2017
Sam 5   6   01/10/2019
Joe 6   7   01/06/2017
Joe 6   7   01/07/2017
Joe 6   7   01/08/2017
Joe 6   7   01/10/2018
Joe 6   7   01/08/2020
Joe 6   8A  01/09/2017
Joe 6   8A  01/07/2018
Joe 6   8A  01/08/2018
Joe 6   8A  01/09/2018
Joe 6   8A  01/09/2020
Joe 6   8A  01/10/2020
Joe 6   8A  01/11/2020
Joe 7   8A  01/09/2017
Joe 7   8A  01/03/2018
Joe 7   8A  01/12/2020
Joe 7   8A  01/01/2021
Joe 7   8A  01/02/2021
Joe 7   8A  01/03/2021
```

**all I need the specific date the student had jump Jo should have only 2 rows jump 7 and jump 8a

hope explained it properly please ask me if I have not.

Many Thanks**

Comment: This is a very incomplete and unclear question. [Edit] to fix it: Show schemas of tables, sample input data, desired output data, current output and an explanation of what exactly is wrong with it. Also, tag _which_ implementation of SQL you are using.

Comment: I need the number of grade change, for example Ali - had a change of grade from 2 to 3 on 01/02/2020 then had another jump fro 3 to 5 on 20/05/2021 just two rows for ALI or JOE should have 3 rows showing jump from 6 to 7 with date of grade improvement/jump then 7 to 8a with a date grade changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to get which date they had change of grade i.e from grade 3a to 3b as jump1 and from 3b to 5 jump2 with the relevant date.

This sounds like conditional aggregation with `lag()`:

```
select studentid,
       min(case when grade = '3b' and prev_grade = '3a' then censusdate end) as trans_3b_from_3a,
       min(case when grade = '5' and prev_grade = '3b' then censusdate end) as trans_5_from_3b
from (select gh.*,
             lag(grade) over (partition by studentid order by censusdate) as prev_grade
      from Gradehistory gh
      where band is not null
     ) gh
group by studentid;
```

If you don't really care about the transition but only want the earliest date for each band, then this is even simpler:

```
select studentid,
       min(case when grade = '3b' then censusdate end) as trans_3b_from_3a,
       min(case when grade = '5' then censusdate end) as trans_5_from_3b
from Gradehistory gh
where band is not null
group by studentid
```

Comment: Gordon Thanks you so much, I changed it a little bit and it worked perfect for what i was looking for, the clue was the Lag and partition to get previous row. You are brilliant and helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

When you group by the student and the grade, you can get the `min(jumpgradedate)` which should be the date you're looking for.

If I understand you correct:

```
SELECT studentID, jumpgrade, min(jumpgradedate) from ...
group by studentID, jumpgrade
```

---

edit:

What if you change your last part to:

```
SELECT distinct A.StudentID,A.Grade as lowGrade ,B.Grade as Jumpgrade, min(B.GradeDate) as JumpGradeDate
FROM Grade1 A INNER JOIN Grade2 B ON A.StudentID=B.StudentID
WHERE A.Grade < B.Grade 
GROUP BY A.StudentID, A.Grade, B.Grade
ORDER BY A.StudentID, a.Grade, min(JumpGradeDate) ASC
```

Comment: I need the number of  grade change, for example Ali - had a change of grade from 2 to 3 on 01/02/2020 then had another jump fro 3 to 5 on 20/05/2021 just two rows for ALI  or JOE should have 3 rows showing jump from 6 to 7 with date of grade improvement/jump  then 7 to 8a  with a date grade changed

Comment: Yea. This is just what my query does. 
The "group by" only returns one row if all  the columns havent changes..  That would manke 2 rows for  Joe, and the get the lowest date from that collection which is the date of the jump.

Comment: if you check the table posted at the end of my post the repeated rows coming through because the table holding daily record of student so I am getting the 18 rows for JOE I only need those rows he had Grade jump fro 6 to 7 and 7 to 8a.

Comment: I've edited my ansver to clarify what I mean.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help the script from Gordon was what i was looking for.